# How to add a placeholder in an ActiveX textbox in an excel sheet?

Tags: vba

In an excel worksheet, I have an ActiveX textbox (not from a UserForm) where I want to put placeholders in it, and when the user types his data down, the placeholder goes away.

Comment: You would need to implement your own *watermark* functionality, since ActiveX textboxes don't have any feature like it. Probably something along the lines of defaulting to some "placeholder text" content with a grey-ish foreground, and then a lot of hair-pulling involving the `Change` handler and some `Boolean` flag that indicates whether the content is placeholder text or actual legit user input - but that will never look as good as an actual watermarked textbox such as what you could do with, say, WPF in .NET. If you want a modern UI, use a modern UI framework. MSForms is well over 20yo.

Comment: In any case, this is *a lot* of work and effort, and this isn't a "please code XYZ for me" site. Get started, eventually get stuck on a specific problem, *then* ask about *that* specific problem - you'll have a much better Stack Overflow experience then. Cheers!